# Pesquisa numa array em javascript

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmo-de-busca

Como fazer uma pesquisa dentro de uma array em javascript?

A solução que uso é uma gambiarra.

```
x = ['a','b','c','d'];

if ( x.indexOf('a') != -1) {

    console.log('Verdadeiro');

} else {
    console.log('Falso');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jonas, a maneira que estás a usar é a maneira historicamente correta.

Existe agora uma maneira nova, que já está disponivel na maioria dos Browsers que é [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) e que faz parte de ECMAScript 2016. Com esta nova sintaxe poderias usar:

```js
x = ['a','b','c','d'];

if (x.includes('a')) console.log('Verdadeiro');
else console.log('Falso');
```

Answer (score 0):

Está correto usar `Array().indexOf`, essa é a única maneira de descobrir a índice de um elemento específico em uma `Array`, percorrendo ela mesma.

Portanto, você poderia fazer um polyfill para funcionar em todos navegadores.

**Edit:** Tive que crescer o código do polyfill porque o MSIE6 é um navegador bastante *estreito*. `i++`, em vez de incrementar o `i` depois de retornar seu próprio valor, acaba retornando o `i` incrementado.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)

    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(item) {
        var me = this;
        /* Percore a array até achar um item igual à @item. */
        for (var i = 0, l = me.length; i < l && (me[i] === item ? false : true); i++);
        return i < l ? i : -1;
    };
```